# XML - Error Parsing XML - Eclipse Android Project

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I always get the same error message for my XML-Document in a Androidproject.

My code:
(The error occures in the last line)

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context = ".SelectActivity" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have closing tag for your TableLayout which is

```
</TableLayout>
```

Also this @dimen is this a resource or an id?

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: I don´t really know. These lines were created automatically by creating the Eclipse Project...

Comment: This was just a little excerpt. I have a closing tag for TableLayout ;)

Comment: According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:paddingBottom) it should be a numeric value, could be sp or dp. Can you remove it or change it to numeric value (example 10dp or 15sp but dp is recommended)?

Comment: I have replace the dimension resource with 10dp for each attribute. The error still occures.

Comment: What is the parent layout of the TableLayout? Can you post the entire content of the XML?

Comment: There is no parent layout.

Comment: Try to wrap it with LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. By the way is the error message on the XML?